# User selects the number of prompt boxes to display

Tags: javascript, user-controls, user-input, prompt

Trying to write a javascript code
That will enable user to select the number of prompt boxes.

Like,The prompt box will say, how many prompts do you want. Then if the user inputs 2. Two prompt box will show and if user inputs 3 or 4. That number of prompt boxes will show.

```
    let num = Number(prompt('Enter the number of prompts:'));

if (num=1){
  let name1 = prompt('Enter first user name:');
  let age1 = prompt('Enter first user age');
  
  
  console.log(name1)
  console.log(age1);
}
  
else if (num=2){
  let name1 = prompt('Enter first user name:');
  let age1 = prompt('Enter first user age');
  
  let name2 = prompt('Enter second user name:');
  let age2 = prompt('Enter second user age');
  
  console.log(name1);
  console.log(age1);
  
  console.log(name2)
  console.log(age2);
}
else{
  let name1 = prompt('Enter first user name:');
  let age1 = prompt('Enter first user age');
  
  let name2 = prompt('Enter second user name:');
  let age2 = prompt('Enter second user age');
  
  let name3 = prompt('Enter third user name:');
  let age3 = prompt('Enter third user age');
  
  
  console.log(name1)
  console.log(age1);
  
  console.log(name2)
  console.log(age2);
  
  console.log(name3)
  console.log(age3);
  
}
```

Comment: ok, show us what you're trying. Formatted code please. Make a snippet if you can (`<>` button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use a for loop.

```
let num = Number(prompt('Enter the number of prompts:'));

const data = [];

for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  let name = prompt(`Enter user ${i}'s name:`);
  let age = prompt(`Enter user ${i}'s age:`);

  data.push({ name, age });
}

data.forEach(d => {
  console.log(d.name);
  console.log(d.age);
});
```

Simplify it by rewording the prompts so you can use the index of the current position in the loop.

If you want everything to be logged at the end, keep all the answers in an array, and iterate through that array at the end to log the answers.

Comment: Thanks for your ans. I'm very new to javascript and programming in general. I still don’t know a lot of things. But this gets it done what i was trying to achieve.

Comment: No problem! We all started from complete ignorance, so don't be discouraged! Just keep building things and it'll come.